# How to use CPPCMS base content classes

Tags: c++, templates

I am creating a small facts site as an experiment to create an extremely efficient website from c++ using cppcms.

I am having a problem in deciding how to create a base_content class for the templates to access.

In my class structure, I have created a container class, called Fact, which uses getters and setters to managed the variables, inheriting from IContainer.

In order to avoid copying the data into a separate class, I had to inherit cppcms::base_content in IContainer and expose the private variables in Fact (so the template could directly access them).

Is there a way I can either, create and access pointers to data in a container class from the separate content class, or (better still) call the getters (returning either const int or const string) of fact from within the template, with the Fact object acting as the content class.

If clarification is needed, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you use getter in template:

```
class Fact : public cppcms::base_content {
public:
      std::string get_foo() const;
      void set_foo(std::string const &v) const;
private:
      std::string foo_;
};
```

And in the template

```
<%= get_foo() %>
```

In any case if you have many fields with getter/setter that only do "get" and "set"
than you probably should consider make them public and not use getters/setters at all.